# Timeout error occurred trying to start MySQL Daemon

Tags: linux, mysql, centos5

Timeout error occurred trying to start MySQL Daemon.

The above error comes when i run the following command "service mysqld start"

this error comes on centos 5 after reboot the system

please help me i'm a new bie on centos 5 and i'm stuck here

Answer (score 1):

Check if mysql process isn't already running.

Also check in my.cnf if you have correct bind-address parameter set. It could be either `0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1` or your external IP. If it's some other IP, it could cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old. I'm just adding a post for anyone else that has this issue and finds this thread while looking for an answer.

We had the same error after rebooting a RHEL5 server. In our case, the mysql user's UID and primary group were changed, so the database did not have access to any files in /var/lib/mysql.